# mongoDB matching localdatetime when using aggregation

Tags: mongodb

When I use mongdbTemplate to aggregate ,it creates sentence like this:

```js
db.trade.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "buyer.employeeId": "2c901f5c7227936901722ab946ba000f",
      "tradeState.payTime": {
        "$gte": {
          "$date": 1630425600000
        },
        "$lte": {
          "$date": 1633017599999
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$buyer.employeeId",
      "sumTotalPrice": {
        "$sum": "$tradePrice.totalPrice"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I cannot use this to check whether it’s correct in shell order ,because it’s using timestamp to match. but the question is I cannot get any result with sentence above in code.

I’ve checked the timestamp is converted by Localdatetime，and the number is correct.

Comment: the question is how to convert timestamp to a date? [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AbNzd6pLrxw) converts timestamp to a date maybe this is what you want, its using the `$toDate` operator

Comment: the question is  how can i check the sentence is right？